# How to run Ms access function from a button via web browser control of my form

Tags: javascript, function, webbrowser-control, ms-access-2013

I am going to run a function I made in a my project module, for instance this:

```
public function Test()
Msgbox "hello"
End function
```

via a button of web browser control of ms-access form.
for example:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="RUN TEST FUNCTION">show message</button>
```

Please help me how to do this work.

Comment: Is this from a normal browser?, Then you can't, it would be a massive security issue if you could.

Comment: But several days ago I found a post in youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgOny5vG8DA) aboat it. I downloaded example handleview of it from githube. That was very complicated and I thought maybe anybody could help me

Comment: Oh, your wanting to use webview inside ms access.  For some reason i thought you was wanting to control access from browser.  In that case have you looked at the gitHub link he has posted? https://github.com/BluejacketSoftware/HandleView ,   I don't use access, but i assume you download his repo and open the `app.accdb` file.

Comment: Exactly, but now I want to run a vba function  via a button of web browser control on my ms access form. I have handleview sample but it,s very complicated. I expect anybody help me and  simplify that and tell me a answer. Thanks again.